# Reading Files when application launch at startup

Tags: c++, windows, inno-setup

I recently created a c++ program for windows that when is launched, it reads some  files that store the  user configurations, if it is the first time the program runs, it store the options the user set and create the files. When I am debugging it in visual studio it works as expected.

So I proceded to create a setup for installation, I used Inno Setup. My program requiered to start at launch so I use the following code, this is from the inno website http://www.jrsoftware.org/iskb.php?startwithwindows. My problem is that when the programs start at launch these files are not read or created, but if I close the program and I launch the program using the desktop Icon it reads and creates de files.

So my question is there something in the Inno script that allows it to read the files? could be a problem with the fstream class?, could there be a code solution

Thanks in advance.

I followed Michael advice and I used the APPDATA folder with Roaming subfolder, and now the program read the config files and run as expected, thanks for the help!!.

Comment: Code solution ? Do you have now a problem in code or do you need one ? Give more details about what you are doing in your c++ app.

Comment: What directory are you attempting to write the file(s) to? Does the application have the appropriate permissions to the file(s)/directory at runtime?

Comment: If you're using relative paths make sure your current working directory is correct.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am not using relative paths, the files are created and store in the same folder of the .exe. When I install my program I store it in the (x86) folder, but I thought it could a permission problems and I install it in C:// but the same problem of not reading the files still happens.

Comment: If Michael's answer resolved your problem, you should accept it, by clicking on the tick-mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From above comments, you say you are storing the configuration files in the same folder as the .exe, and your application is able to create the files when run from Visual Studio, but not when installed to the "Program Files (x86)" folder or C:/ root.

It sounds like you are running into UAC (User Access Control) permissions issues. The "Program Files (x86)" folder at least, and I believe C:/ (root) as well, require administrator privileges to write. This was not the case with Windows XP and older; it is with modern versions. You may be running Visual Studio as administrator and not know it, and allowing administrator privileges when you install, but the application is not then run as administrator so it cannot write to those locations.

Try running your (installed) application as administrator (right-click the file and select "Run as administrator"). If it works, there you go: you either have to run it as administrator always if you want it to be able to store configuration files in the same directory as the .exe, or else (much better solution) store your configuration files in an appropriately-named subdirectory of %APPDATA%, which the user running your application will always be able to write to without administrator privileges.

Comment: It is probably not that Visual Studio is running as administrator, but that the program has the requireAdministrator option set in its manifest, since the OP says it works when run from the desktop.   IIRC, when programs are started via the Run key or the Startup folder, the requireAdministrator option is silently ignored.  The resolution, as you say, is to not store the files next to the executable.  Depending on the scenario, the ProgramData folder (aka the global application data folder, aka CommonAppDataFolder) might be more sensible than the user's application data folder